# (Android) Get a link to a Facebook album

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app uploads a photo to a unique album within the Facebook profile of the user, and also makes a wall post separately. I want to get the link to the album the photo was uploaded to so I can display the album link in the subsequent wall post.

```
imageParams.putByteArray("picture", byteArray);
        String albumID = facebookConnector.getFacebook().request("me/photos",imageParams,"POST");
```

Uploads the image and stores the ID in a String variable.

```
getParams.putString("link", link);
        facebookConnector.getFacebook().request("me/albums", getParams, "GET");
```

This is the bit I likely need help with, as I'm not sure I'm asking it for what I want in a way that the request understands. How can I get the url 'link' value stored within the album object for the album identified with the albumID variable?